# Laravel directory structure best practice

Tags: laravel, shell, directory, structure

What is the best practice to put my customized shell script in Laravel directory ? 
According to https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/structure all the folders has their own purposes. Currently i have 3 to 4 shell scripts, my controller will call the shell scripts when the user click submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Shell scripts are are stored in `Kernel.php` of course. They are handled by `Command` in `Console/Commands` in `handle()` method. In there I would recommend you to make a `service`. For example:

```
public function handle(CustomService $customService) {
        $customService->calledMethod();
}
```

This structure keeps the code clean and it's easier to make `phpunit/tests` for that.